# Преобразование массива JSON в массив JavaScript

Tags: json, javascript

Добрый день. Имеется такой массив:

```
var json_data = [{"city":"Shanghai","pop":23.7},{"city":"Lagos","pop":16,"0":1},{"city":"Instanbul","pop":14.2}]
```

Как в JavaScript преобразовать его в вид двухмерного массива:

```
[['Shanghai', 23.7],['Lagos', 16,1],['Instanbul', 14.2]]
```

Может как-то через JSON.parse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = [];
for(var k in json_data) {
  var v = json_data[k];
  result.push(k, v);
}
```

Получится:

```
[['0', 1], ['Shanghai', 23.7],['Lagos', 16],['Instanbul', 14.2]]
```

Получить `['Lagos', 16,1]` не получится, потому что в js-объектах неупорядоченное множество пар ключ-значение.
Т.е. исходный объект ничем не отличается скажем от:

```
var json_data = {"0":1,"Shanghai":23.7,"Lagos":16,"Instanbul":14.2};
```

**Update**

```
var json_data = [{"city":"Shanghai","pop":23.7},{"city":"Lagos","pop":16,"0":1},{"city":"Instanbul","pop":14.2}];
var result = [];
json_data.forEach(function(city){
  var el = [city.city, city.pop];
  if(city[0]) el.push(city[0]);
  result.push(el);
});
```

Comment: @Alexander Deider, да я ошибся немного с начальным массивом, он представляет собой двухмерный массив. Из такого можно сделать двухмерный массив для JS? У вас получается массив 0,['Shanghai', 23.7],1,['Lagos', 16],2,['Instanbul', 14.2], а мне нужно просто ['Shanghai', 23.7],['Lagos', 16],['Instanbul', 14.2]

Comment: а я как раз написал решение под новый формат)

Answer (score 2):

JSON тут ни при чем. Ваш `json_data` - это обычный JS-объект с четырьмя полями. Пройдитесь по нему обычным циклом

```
for (key in json_data) { ... }
```

и склейте в какой угодно массив.

Comment: @IntegralAL, это то что вам нужно?

    var json_data = [{"city":"Shanghai","pop":23.7},{"city":"Lagos","pop":16,"0":1},{"city":"Instanbul","pop":14.2}];
    var a = [];
    for (var i=0; i< json_data.length; i++) {
     a.push([json_data[i].city, json_data[i].pop]);
    }